# Ajax redirected page won't save input fields cache

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I have an ajax submit input field which on success redirects the page.
For this redirection I use `ctools_ajax_command_redirect()` which works great.

My only concern is that the fields will not save the entered values in the browser cache.
I.e. email inputs usually have a list of previously entered emails when using the down key on the field.
As non ajax submitted fields do keep this info I wonder how can I tweek my ajax calls to force the cache.

This is my form:

```
$form['email'] = array(
    '#type' => 'emailfield',
    '#title' => t('Email'),
    '#element_validate' => NULL,
    '#id' => 'edit-email',
);
$form['continue'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Continue'),
    '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'my_form_callback',
        'event' => 'click',
    ),
    '#id' => 'edit-continue',
);
```

This is my ajax redirection function:

```
function my_form_callback($form, $form_state) {
  if ($success) {
    ctools_include('ajax');
    ctools_add_js('ajax-responder');
    $commands[] = ctools_ajax_command_redirect($url, 0, $options);
    print ajax_render($commands);
    exit;
  }
}
```

**Any hint on how I could make the field save the cache values?**

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't think this is really a Drupal question, and answers will probably vary per-browser

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll try to figure out a solution and post it back here.